# Capturing just the `PID` field from `netstat`

Tags: parsing, powershell-2.0

Doing web development, I have a process that periodically just hangs.

I'd like to kill it with a PowerShell script.

From what I can tell, the `netstat` command seems to return a string instead of a friendly object with easily accessed properties.  In my reading, I haven't found a power-shell friendly replacement, though I am open to one.

```
function killport($port) {
    // How do I capture the $PID from here?
    netstat -ao | findstr $port
    write-host Taskkill /PID $pid 
    sleep 5
    write-host Taskkill /PID $pid /f
}
```

Sample run:

```
netstat -ao | findstr 51135
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51135        r151:51135             ESTABLISHED     7968
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you'll only get the one result (which seems likely), you can use a simple regex to capture the last group of digits from the line.

```
$netstat = "TCP    127.0.0.1:51135        r151:51135             ESTABLISHED     7968";
$PortNumRegex = [regex]"(\d+)$";
$portnum = $PortNumRegex.Match($netstat);
$portnum.captures[0].Value;
```

In your case, replace the `$netstat` line with `netstat -ao | findstr 51135`; you could also eliminate `findstr 51135` by running the output of `netstat -ao` through `select-string` or other regex matches, but for a simple case like this, the above should work just fine.

Comment: Excellent, appears to be exactly what I need.  Thanks for the info on `select-string` too.

Comment: Replace the first line with: `$netstat = & "netstat.exe" -ao | findstr 0:51135;`
And replace the last line of the script with: `$pidTask = $portnum.captures[0].Value;
Taskkill /PID $pidTask
`